# MySQL query to generate table of dates, items, and counts per month

Tags: mysql, count

I am close to figuring this out, but need a nudge to finish. My dataset has records for January, February, and March.

```
enter code here

Select
  cartypes.TypeName,
  Count(cartypes.TypeName) As Count,
  COUNT(MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 1) As Jan,
  COUNT(MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 2) As Feb
From maindata
  Inner Join cartypes
    On maindata.TypeID = cartypes.CarType_ID
Group By cartypes.TypeName
```

my output looks like this:

```
TypeName                      Count      Jan    Feb 
Accreditation Audit            23        1       0
Certificate Decision            5        1       0
Certification Decision          2        1       0
Complaint About Client          1        1       0
Customer Complaint              3        1       0
Internal Audit                  5        1       0 
Internal Finding                7        1       0
Preventative Action             1        1       0
Witness Audit                   1        0       1
```

I have tried several different methods to try to get the counts for the various TypeName of each record to tally correctly for each month, but I have hit a wall. For example, Jan is supposed to show a count of 23 for the Accreditation Audit, and Feb should have 2 Certification Decisions, and 1 Witness Audit.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: Are you sure that `CreatedDate` is of `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype and that it has no nulls?

Comment: CreatedDate is yyyy-mm-dd formatted timestamp of when the record was created.

Comment: Is it of datatype `TIMESTAMP` or not? Because all these datatypes do not have an inherent format. The default display format is irrelevant.

Comment: datatype for CreatedDate = date (not 'timestamp', I remembered incorrectly), stored as '2013-01-10'

Answer (score 2):

Your current query is very close to the final query.  You will want to use a `CASE` expression to get the count in each month for each `TypeName`:

```
Select
  cartypes.TypeName,
  Count(cartypes.TypeName) As Count,
  sum(case when MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) As Jan,
  sum(case when MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) As Feb
From maindata
Inner Join cartypes
  On maindata.TypeID = cartypes.CarType_ID
Group By cartypes.TypeName
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7729a/1).

Or you can use `COUNT` with the `CASE`:

```
Select
  cartypes.TypeName,
  Count(cartypes.TypeName) As Count,
  count(case when MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 1 then cartypes.TypeName end) As Jan,
  count(case when MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 2 then cartypes.TypeName end) As Feb
From maindata
Inner Join cartypes
  On maindata.TypeID = cartypes.CarType_ID
Group By cartypes.TypeName
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7729a/2)

Both queries give the result:

```
|               TYPENAME | COUNT | JAN | FEB |
----------------------------------------------
|    Accreditation Audit |     4 |   3 |   1 |
|   Certificate Decision |     1 |   0 |   1 |
| Certification Decision |     3 |   1 |   2 |
| Complaint About Client |     3 |   3 |   0 |
|     Customer Complaint |     3 |   0 |   3 |
|         Internal Audit |     2 |   2 |   0 |
|       Internal Finding |     1 |   1 |   0 |
|    Preventative Action |     5 |   0 |   5 |
|          Witness Audit |     5 |   4 |   1 |
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you.  Please contrast with what I have posted below, and comment as to which would be the better practice.

Comment: The difference is that your syntax will only work on MySQL. The `CASE`  syntax works on all database products.

Comment: Thank you bluefeet. That is very helpful to know.

Comment: Yes, in MySQL you don't even have to use the `IF()` function, you can write `SUM(MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = 1) As Jan, ...` and it will work because `TRUE` is `1` and `FALSE` is `0` (again, only in MySQL.)

Answer (score 1):

By changing:

```
COUNT(MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = X) as [Jan,Feb,etc]

to

SUM(IF(MONTH(maindata.CreatedDate) = X, 1,0)) as [Jan,Feb,etc]
```

the columns for Jan, Feb, etc now have the correct values, which when aggregated across all months, is equal to the Count value for the TypeName.